# What is the meaning of () in this code of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, async-await

I am new learner of `JavaScript`. I saw the following code somewhere but can't understand why there is `(` before `async` and `()` after that? I know arrow functions in JavaScript but it seems this is a little different?

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=46741025610365786#",
    { waitUntil: "networkidle2" }
  );
  await page.click(".menu2 .violet", { button: "left" });
  await page.waitForSelector(".content .awesome", { timeout: 20000 });
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#ClientTypeBody tr"));
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < trs.length; i += 6) {
      arr.push(trs[i].innerText
          .replace(new RegExp("\t", "g"), ", ")
          .replace(new RegExp("حجم", "g"), "")
          .replace(/ \([^)]+\)/g, "")
          .replace(",", ""));
      arr.push('\n');
    }
    return arr.toString();
  });
  fs.writeFile("store.txt", data, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("The file has been saved!");
  });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

What are the inputs/outputs of this function? ? Why the `async` is inside of a `()` and there is also a blank `()` in front of it?

Comment: Terms to google are IIFE and arrow functions.

Comment: It's that dupe but with an arrow function instead of `function() { }`. And `() => {}` is an arrow function that takes no arguments.

Comment: It's an arrow method calling anonymously